# Count duplicate columns and update the counter column

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Report table Columns:
ID | ipaddress | count | category
```

I have duplicate ipaddress entries, I want to count the number of each IP and 
**update** the count column for each IP.

I'm able to count the duplicates like so

```
SELECT ipaddress, COUNT(*) FROM report GROUP BY ipaddress HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

**Output**

```
 ipaddress       COUNT(*) 
192.168.2.187        16
192.168.6.14         14
192.168.2.17         11
3192.168.3.6         9
192.168.2.77         8
```

I just need to update each ip with its correct count number.

Answer (score 1):

You can `JOIN` in an `UPDATE`, like so:

```
UPDATE report r
  JOIN (SELECT ipaddress, COUNT(*) cnt FROM report GROUP BY ipaddress) up
    ON up.ipaddress = r.ipaddress
   SET r.`count` = up.cnt
```